# Couldn't find Post with 'id'=

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to link to a page that will show top responses for each post, however when I set everything up and click on the link_to button I get the error message:

> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Post with 'id'=):

I have this in my views:

```
  <% if @post.user == current_user && @post.responses.where(top: true).size >= 1 %>
      <a href="#" class="btt"><%= link_to "finalize top", '/top' %>Finalize Top</a>
```

And I have my /top route set to show the top responses page:

```
get '/top' => 'responses#top'
```

I understand that Rails doesn't know which post I'm referring to, but I'm not sure what needs to change in the views, routes, or responses controller.

I also have this in the responses controller which I thought would help but didn't:

```
def top
  @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
end
```

Any help is highly appreciated! This is my first time posting and am completely new to Ruby on Rails and programming.

Here is the full error from Terminal:

```
Started GET "/top" for ::1 at 2017-01-21 21:17:03 -0500
Processing by ResponsesController#top as HTML
  Post Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", nil]]
Completed 404 Not Found in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.1ms)

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Post with 'id'=):
  app/controllers/responses_controller.rb:46:in `set_post'
```

Comment: What do your migration tables look like? Is there a post_id field?

Comment: There is a post_id field for the responses table:   create_table "responses", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "post_id"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.text     "body"
    t.datetime "created_at",                 null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                 null: false
    t.boolean  "top",        default: false
  end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First `link_to` is similar to `<a>` so in your view, you should putting `link_to` inside an `<a>` is like putting an `<a>` inside another `<a>`.
In your view put:

```
<% if @post.user == current_user && @post.responses.where(top: true).size >= 1 %>
      <%= link_to "finalize top", { controller: :responses, action: :top, id: @post.id },{ class: 'btn btn-default'} %>
```

In your controller:

```
def top
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end
```

In routes.rb

```
get '/top' => 'responses#top'
```

Comment: Thanks Anass, I have hope again. I also had to change the def set_post to just :id instead of :post_id and it worked. Thanks again and I will upvote this when I earn some more points on stackoverflow.

Comment: This is what programmers are meant to do helping each other, i' m glad i could have helped you

Answer (score 0):

I would try:

```
def top
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end
```

Comment: It's giving me the same exact error for some reason after trying this.

Comment: Also want to add that the line that the error is pointing to is the def set_post in responses controller: Extracted source (around line #46): private
    def set_post
      @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    end